# VSCode Setting to push JavaScript objects inside arrays to new line

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

Is there a VS Code extension setting that, when using formatOnSave, will force object-literal curly-brackets for the first object in an array to start on the next line?

Trying to achieve this:

```
const arrOfObjs = [
  {
    name: 'Obj1'
  },
  {
    name: 'Obj2'
  }
];
```

But instead, the formatter brings the first obj curly up on the same line as the array bracket:

```
const arrOfObjs = [{
    name: 'Obj1'
  },
  {
    name: 'Obj2'
  }
];
```

That makes ESLint yell about indents (expecting 2 but found 4). Right now I am ignoring the error for the one time in my code this happens, but I'll continue to feel dirty until I can get these two things to work together. :)

Comment: probably is not prettier, you are using a linter? which setting are you using for prettier and the linter

Comment: @ramirozap Updated the question to remove mention of Prettier (this happens in stock VSCode), add that I'm using ESLint, and added what the error is (indent expecting 2 but found 4). The eslint settings are used company-wide, so changing them isn't an option. Does that help clarify?

Comment: you probably have some conflicting rules between your editor and eslint and both are formatting at the same time, put: `"editor.formatOnSave": false` and `"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,`

Comment: @ramirozap That requires the vscode-eslint extension, right? Was hoping to avoid needing an extension, but it seems like that will work. Can you add as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably is a conflict between VSCode and ESLin, both are formatting at the same time, let ESLint manage the formatting put: `"editor.formatOnSave": false` and `"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true`

Comment: Thanks, @ramirozap. I actually didn't realize I had the ESLint VS Code extension installed. That did it.